# How to disable "Deceptive site ahead" on JS while ping request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, ping, url-validation

I have interesting behavior in my JS code when I try to send PING request to website which is marked as DANGEROUS by chrome for example:

I try to type in input field the website url reddit.com, my js checks all combinations from start:

```
1)  r - (1) invalid url
2)  re - (1) invalid url
3)  red - (1) invalid url
4)  redd - (1) invalid url
5)  reddi - (1) invalid url
6)  reddit - (1) invalid url
7)  reddit. - (1) invalid url
8)  reddit.c - (1) invalid url
9)  reddit.co - (1) url valid, (2) check is url exists
10) reddit.com - this step can't be reached because big full-screen error from previous step
```

**on step 8 everything is ok**
[image]

**on step 9 I have big full-screen error: Deceptive site ahead ...**
[image]

How to handle this behavior, and just let user to choose it, if he really wants it.

My JS code which make PING

```
export function fetch_with_timeout(url, options, timeout = 7000) {
   return Promise.race([
      fetch(url, options),
      new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), timeout)),
   ]);
}
```

Comment: You can't. As long as HTTP request is sent to malicious site, Chrome would block it. There is no way to workaround this through JavaScript. Otherwise, it would be a big security problem in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

So the only solution I see is to make ping request to the server which actually  executes ping and respond with web-resource availability.

request

```
{ "url": "reddit.co" }
```

responce

```
{ "url": "reddit.co", "available": true }
```